# Trouble Cloning and Running a React Project

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I am a beginner and want to run a React project on my local machine.  I cloned the project and `cd` into it and then run `npm install`.  Then, I installed the dependencies using `yarn install`.  Finally, I run `npm start`, but what shows up in my browser is the React logo and a message saying `Edit src/App.js and save to reload.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know that the project works/runs and do you know what it's supposed to do?

Comment: It seems that your're using create react app, in that case the react logo means that the app is running. You're doing it right

Comment: @KevinHooke yes I had a coworker show me some screenshots of it running on his local when he gave me access to the repo

Answer (score 0):

The only wrong thing is that you ran `yarn install` after `npm install`, that two commands do the same thing.

That react logo and message is the app running, open App.js in an editor a try changing the text to see how it updates on the browser.

Comment: This is app.js, what should be changed?:

https://pastebin.com/uHSzzWtc

Comment: Anything, like the "Edit src/App.js and save to reload" text, then save to reload, and now see if it has changed.

Comment: it sounds like what you're seeing though is the skeleton of a React app created with create-react-app. Are you sure you cloned the right repo, or is this all the repo contains (a skeleton React app containing just the app.js)?

Comment: Could it be that when I am cloning, since I only have reporter access that I am not getting the actual repo?

Comment: @KevinHooke I changed the text in App.js and I see it updated on the browser... but still can't see the actual project?!  Appreciate your help with this!

Comment: Maybe you are on the wrong git branch, use `git branch -a` to list all branches

Comment: @DC1117 do you see the source files that you expect to see if you look at the filesystem inside the cloned project folder?

Comment: Apparently the project files are the issue.  After looking at the repo more closely I can see there was only one commit that was to create the initial react app and the files haven't been updated since then, so I feel quite stupid.  Anyway, thank you both for your time and help.

Comment: Yep... that was definitely the problem.  Just was able to get another project up and running no issues.  Thanks again.